# Почему не работает PngQuant?

Tags: php, composer, png

Установил на сервер [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/php.html), а он не работает. Ошибка следующая:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Conversion to compressed PNG failed. Is pngquant 1.8+ installed on the server?`

Версия на сервере `1.0-4.1` установлено на `Debian Wheezy` это вот про версию я чет не сосем понял, какая именно у меня, но кажется та что нужно.

```
function compress_png($path_to_png_file, $max_quality = 90)
{
    if (!file_exists($path_to_png_file)) {
        throw new Exception("File does not exist: $path_to_png_file");
    }

    // guarantee that quality won't be worse than that.
    $min_quality = 60;

    // '-' makes it use stdout, required to save to $compressed_png_content variable
    // '<' makes it read from the given file path
    // escapeshellarg() makes this safe to use with any path
    $compressed_png_content = shell_exec("pngquant --quality=$min_quality-$max_quality - < ".escapeshellarg($path_to_png_file));

    if (!$compressed_png_content) {
        throw new Exception("Conversion to compressed PNG failed. Is pngquant 1.8+ installed on the server?");
    }

return $compressed_png_content;
}

$path_to_uncompressed_file = 'test.png';
$path_to_compressed_file = 'test-small.png';
if (!file_exists($path_to_compressed_file)) {
file_put_contents($path_to_compressed_file,    compress_png($path_to_uncompressed_file));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы ставили через:

`apt-get install pngquant`

То скорее всего у вас поставилась 1-ая версия

```
$ pngquant 
pngquant, version 1.0 of 5 April 2002, by Greg Roelofs.
   Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.49.
   Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.4; using zlib 1.2.7.
```

Первая версия у меня выдаёт такую же ошибку как и у вас. Да и вообще ничего не получается в ней ужать.

А на [оф. сайте pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) сказано **не использовать версию 1.0 pngquant**.

Попробуйте удалить и поставить из репозитория свежую версию:

```
sudo apt-get remove pngquant
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
git clone git://github.com/pornel/pngquant.git
cd pngquant
./configure
make
```

Проверим версию:

```
$ ./pngquant --version
2.5.2 (October 2015)
```

После этого остаётся в вашем коде в `shell_exec` указать правильный путь до собранной либы pngquant (куда вы установили pngquant).

После установки свежей версии pngcrush png начали сжиматься. Кстати, где pngcrush сжимал в 1,2 раза, pngquant ужал в 4 раза!

Comment: где именно в коде это указать?

Comment: А куда вы клонировали pngquant? Без ошибок всё собралось?

Comment: точно по вашему коду

Comment: а, `pwd` какой текущий путь выводит?

Comment: вот `/root/pngquant`

Comment: Тогда вот так:
$compressed_png_content = shell_exec("/root/pngquant --quality=

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29778/discussion-between-jekaby-and-emtecif).